# Understanding an SDRAM Datasheet

Tags: memory

I am currently working on a reverse engineering project. I am checking out an SDRAM data sheet and it says that the memory chip is organized as 2,097,152 Words × 4 banks × 16 bits

When these values are multiplied the result is: 134217728.

Does the result mean that the SDRAM can store 134217728 bytes?

Another way I thought of it is that, the Chip contains 2,097,152 Bytes x 4 banks, which are 16 Bit Aligned.

Comment: This is not a programming question. It may be suited for http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the result mean that the SDRAM can store 134217728 bytes?

No, that's *bits*, not bytes. And your brain will find it much easier to work in 'Kilo', or 'Mega'.

134217728 bits = 128 Megabits (Mb) = 16 Megabytes (MB)

Comment: Argh, How would I make that mistake.